# Laravel javascript require perfect-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix, perfect-scrollbar

I try to require the jquery pulgin `perfect-scrollbar` to my laravel javascript. So I have runed

```
npm install perfect-scrollbar
```

In Line 1 of my Javascript file (located under `ressources/assets/javascript/material-dashboard/myfile.js`) I require the plugin with this attempt

```
require('perfect-scrollbar');
```

The `myscript.js` is required to the `app.js` with `require('./material-dashboard/myscript.js')`

Now the browser console tell me

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function
```

The assets are compiled with

```
npm run dev
```

The content of `myscript.js`

```
require('perfect-scrollbar');

(function() {
  isWindows = navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1 ? true : false;

  if (isWindows) {
    // if we are on windows OS we activate the perfectScrollbar function
    $('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel').perfectScrollbar();

    $('html').addClass('perfect-scrollbar-on');
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('perfect-scrollbar-off');
  }
})();
```

What is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using to initialise it i.e. the `$(...).perfectScrollbar` code?

Comment: The content is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar#how-to-use), to initialise an element with the plugin you should do something like the following:

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';

new PerfectScrollbar(".sidebar .sidebar-wrapper");
new PerfectScrollbar(".main-panel");
```

If you want to use `require` instead of import you would do something like:

```
let PerfectScrollbar = require('perfect-scrollbar').default;
```

Lastly, it doesn't look like the plugin is meant to work with `jQuery` out of the box, however, if you want to use with `jQuery` like you are in your post you could do the following:

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';

$.fn.perfectScrollbar = function (options) {

    return this.each((k, elm) => new PerfectScrollbar(elm, options || {}));
};

$('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel').perfectScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to simplify your job, under bootstrap.js file that handles 
*require('perfect-scrollbar');* 
simply change it to 
*window.PerfectScrollbar = require('perfect-scrollbar').default;* and you will be good to go. Only answers questions if using compiling assets in laravel with bootstrap.js